# unmodifiable Stack

Tags: java, collections, stack

I would need a **readonly / unmodifiable** `java.util.Stack`.

For `List`s there is `Collections.unmodifiableList(...)`, but a `Stack` would be better than a `List` for me.

Is there any possibility to avoid implementing my own `UnmodifiableStack` with all this modifying methods?

Thank you!

Comment: If it's unmodifiable, then you wouldn't be able to push or pop anything.  What do you intend to do with an unmodifiable stack?

Comment: A readonly stack is useless: you can only *read* the top element (and only one).

Comment: ... except the peek/search method -- but you're right. I'll use a List now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since making it unmodifiable prevents pushing and popping, how about just using [Collections.unmodifiableCollection()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection(java.util.Collection)) which returns an unmodifiable Collection and works well with a Stack as input?

Comment: Hmm... actually I have one interface with the method `Stack<Move> getMoves()` and only one implementation should have an `UnmodifiableStack`. So the interface forces a `Stack` and not a `Collection`. Maybe I have to change the architecture :(